# Echarts - On click zoom the selected cell in a heatmap

Tags: reactjs, heatmap, echarts, echarts-for-react

I was looking at a chart tool called echarts, which has a type of chart called heatmap. When I click on a cell, I want it to get bigger and show information about it. You should only zoom in on the cell you chose. I found a datazoom property https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom, but the instructions don't have many examples to show how to zoom in and out. Please find the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bvl4yu) to jsfiddle.

I came across zoom functionality https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/12898#issuecomment-653400002 for heatmap. However, it does not work on mouse click.